# TexLive: Cannot find Arial/OT.mf. ! Package fontspec Error: The font "Arial" cannot be found

Tags: fonts, xetex, fontspec, texlive, xepersian

OS: Windows 10 Pro

Hi everyone!
last night I compiled an old Tex file using XeLaTex and texlive2019. These errors happened:

> Package fontspec: The font "Arial" cannot be found.
> Font TU/Arial(0)/m/n/20.74=Arial/OT at 20.74pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file or installed font not found.

then I tried to compile these simple codes:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xepersian}
\settextfont{Arial}

\begin{document}
سلام
Hello
\end{document}
```

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
Hello
\end{document}
```

for the first one the same compile errors occurred. (I also tried "BNazanin" font instead of "Arial".) 
but the second one compiled successfully.

Then I removed the Texlive2019 and installed Texlive2020 and these errors happend: (for the first code)

> Cannot find Arial/OT.mf.
> ! Package fontspec Error: The font "Arial" cannot be found.

so I installed MiKTeX and now these error occurr in both above codes:

> Cannot load default config file
> fontconfig initialization failed!

and I don't have any idea what is the problem and I wanna kill myself :| Pleeeeeease help me.

Thanks for your Attention.

Comment: well at first stop deinstalling and reinstalling systems. Get first some clue what is wrong. If a font can not be found, it normally means that it is not there. And xepersian is *not* simple code, so better investigate without it. What happens if you use lualatex instead of xelatex and  `\documentclass{article}\usepackage{fontspec} \setmainfont{arial}\begin{document}bla\end{document}`?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer 
Thanks for your reply. I just panicked. 
I want to type in persian so I should use xepersian. shoudn't I? and I try that and it works.

Comment: next time you panic jog around your house, or trink some tea, or kick the wall, or ... but keep your fingers away from the keyboard or the mouse ;-).  Panic is a bad state to be in when solving a computer problem. And get yourself an account at overleaf and try your document there - it compiles fine, and it helps against panic, if one knows that there are working alternatives.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer ok I'm sorry. next time I'll kick the wall :)) I know overleaf but I really want to fix this. what should I do? :(

Comment: well as I wrote: try without xepersian and with lualatex first, to check if it finds arial, if yes look in the log-file if it has an usual path. Then go back to the texlive 2020 installation, and try if xelatex finds the font if you use a file name (`\setmainfont{arial.ttf}` probably, or the full path).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I tried and it found arial. log file was ok and I tried this with XeLaTeX: `\documentclass{article} \usepackage{fontspec}   \setmainfont{arial.ttf} \begin{document} Hellooooo \end{document}` and it worked. but I didn't try with xepersian.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I'm sorry for bothering you. but I compiled `\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xepersian}
\settextfont{Arial}

\begin{document}
سلام
Hello
\end{document}` and this error happend:

`The command name is C:\texlive\2020\bin\win32\mktexmf
Cannot find Arial/OT.mf.
! Package fontspec Error: The font "Arial" cannot be found.` do you have any suggestion? thanks.

Comment: well try with the fail name there too `\settextfont{arial.ttf}`.

Comment: thank you so much! I'm so fool :)).
but what happened exactly? I never had this problem before.

Comment: well using a font through font names is sometimes difficult with xelatex. You could try to run `fc-cache --force`, perhaps this resolves the issue.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I tried that before and I got this: `Fontconfig error: Cannot load default config file`. thanks anyway. I really appreciate your help and time.

Comment: Welcome to the site. You might want to search for the file `fonts.conf` in your TeX directory, and double-check that you aren’t setting the `FONTCONFIG_FILE` environment variable. That’s where the default config file should be.

Comment: You might also try `fc-cache -r -s -v`.

Comment: @Davislor Thanks for your answer. I searched for `fonts.conf` and I found three! `C:\texlive\2020\texmf-var\fonts\conf`, `C:\texlive\2020\tlpkg\tlpostcode\xetex\conf`, `C:\texlive\2019\texmf-var\fonts\conf` . which one is important? and honestly, I don't know what environment variable is. I also try the command and I got `Fontconfig error: Cannot load default config file         Font directories:C:/texlive/2020/texmf-var/fonts/cache: cleaning cache directory                    fc-cache: succeeded`. Thanks again.

Comment: The one in `C:/texlive/2020/texmf-var/fonts/conf/`. Check that it's readable by everybody and not corrupted. Also look at the files under `conf.d`.

Comment: You can check your environment variables by opening up a `cmd.exe` window and typing `set`. If you’ve got a stray configuration setting to the one under `C:\texlive\2019`, that could be messing it up.

Comment: @Davislor Thanks a lot. it fixed.